# How print from ipyparallel engine to the main process?

Tags: python, ipython-parallel

I implemented a parallel function using the ipyparallel library. I would like to ask you if there is a way to print from the engine to the main process? Here what I'm trying to do:

```
import ipyparallel as ipp

rc = ipp.Client()
dview = rc[:]
v = rc.load_balanced_view()
v.block = True
v.map(os.chdir, [os.getcwd()] * len(v))

@v.parallel(block=True)
def my_parallel_function(idp):
    print("I want to print something here")
    return idp+1

# runing my parallel function:
my_parallel_function (range(10))
```

I want to print the message " I want to print something here" in the main process but I don't find anything similar in the documentattion. My intension is to see the progress of my_parallel_function.

Comment: http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/magics.html

Comment: @BedirYilmaz Page not found.

Comment: thank you. https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/magics.html @JokeHuang